# Syncing two colors using jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors, color-picker

If I have two colors, let's say `Red (#ff0000)` and `Dark Red (#850000)`. Is there a way to make it so that when one color is changed, the other changes accordingly?

So for example if I change Red into Blue, Dark Red automatically changes to Dark Blue and so on..

Comment: Do you have a set number of options? If so just make an array.

Comment: No, I'm thinking more along the lines of a color picker. Maybe it's possible to link two "pickers" together and so they would never actually change position, relative to each other?

Comment: In CMYK the only difference between your red(ff0000) and dark red(850000) is K changes from `0%` to `48%`. So I would suggest converting the hex to CMYK and then adding K accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the "#" character, split the string into 3, run parseInt on all 3 parts with a radix 16. If you do this on both, you would know the difference between them based on individual RGB components. Then, use an appropriate event handler to detect when color A changes. Compute the difference due to the color A's change (similar to the process I just described), then apply that to color B. Reverse the process by using toString(16) on each of the integer components of the modified color B, then join those 3 components with a "#" at the beginning to recreate the string. Finally, use the appropriate jQuery to modify the CSS property. Don't forget to account for going over 255 or under 0.